# XAMPP - Wordpress error

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I am using XAMPP as my local host for Wordpress. 'Localhost/wordpress' was working fine 2 days ago but now when I visit it, an error comes up saying "This site can't be reached, localhost refused to connect".

Has anybody got any ideas as I dont want to delete the local host and start again.

Comment: Check if your http server is active at all.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: Ask a cow maybe.

Comment: wow what an idiot

Comment: Come on... Is your question serious? I doubt it. If you installed XAMPP you have a documentation. _Read it_.

Answer (score 0):

Are sure you started your mysql and apache server? if so restart again